# Finetuning a Zero-Shot Text Classification Model with own Labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I've been using the "[MoritzLaurer/DeBERTa-v3-base-mnli-fever-anli](https://huggingface.co/MoritzLaurer/DeBERTa-v3-base-mnli-fever-anli)" to classify text, however it isn't precise enough for specific Labels.

Therefore I want to train and finetune the model to improve its precision on my specific Texts and Labels.

I have a Training Dataset with 1 million lines of text, each labeled with one of 22 different Labels such as "Spam", "Advertisement", Flaming".. etc.

As an example:
"Hey you can buy my program here", Advertisement

I couldn't find that much information about how to further finetune a Zero-Shot Model so I tried it this way:

```
from transformers import DebertaV2Tokenizer, RobertaForSequenceClassification, AdamW
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Load tokenizer and model weights
tokenizer = DebertaV2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('MoritzLaurer/DeBERTa-v3-base-mnli-fever-anli')
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('MoritzLaurer/DeBERTa-v3-base-mnli-fever-anli', num_labels=22)

# Load and preprocess training and testing data
def load_data(file_path):
    posts, labels = [], []
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            post, label = line.strip().split('³')
            posts.append(post)
            labels.append(label)
    return posts, labels

train_posts, train_labels = load_data('mixed_train_data.csv')
test_posts, test_labels = load_data('mixed_test_data.csv')

# Convert labels to numerical format
label_to_index = {
    'Approve': 0,
    'Spam': 1,
    'Ads/Selling/Trading': 2,
    'Foreign Language': 3,
    ...
}

train_labels = [label_to_index[label] for label in train_labels]
test_labels = [label_to_index[label] for label in test_labels]

# Tokenize posts
train_encodings = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    train_posts,
    padding=True,
    return_tensors='pt',  # Use PyTorch tensors
    truncation=True
)

test_encodings = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    test_posts,
    padding=True,
    return_tensors='pt',  # Use PyTorch tensors
    truncation=True
)

train_data = TensorDataset(train_encodings['input_ids'], train_encodings['attention_mask'], torch.tensor(train_labels))
test_data = TensorDataset(test_encodings['input_ids'], test_encodings['attention_mask'], torch.tensor(test_labels))

# Create data loaders
batch_size = 32 
train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_data_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size)

# Define optimizer and loss function
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Fine-tuning loop
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for batch in train_data_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        input_ids, attention_mask, labels = [tensor.to(device) for tensor in batch]
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        loss = loss_function(outputs.logits, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    model.eval()
    total_loss = 0
    total_correct = 0
    total_samples = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in test_data_loader:
            input_ids, attention_mask, labels = [tensor.to(device) for tensor in batch]
            outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
            loss = loss_function(outputs.logits, labels)
            total_loss += loss.item()

            predicted_labels = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=1)
            total_correct += (predicted_labels == labels).sum().item()
            total_samples += len(labels)

    average_loss = total_loss / len(test_data_loader)
    accuracy = total_correct / total_samples
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: Average Loss = {average_loss:.4f}, Accuracy = {accuracy:.4f}")

# Save the fine-tuned model's weights
model.save_pretrained('fine_tuned_deberta_model')
```

however running it like that always returns an error saying:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Me\Documents\ForumAI\New\AI.py", line 92, in <module>
>     outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

[...]

> RuntimeError: index_select(): self indexing axis dim should be positive
```

I couldn't find out how to solve that error yet.

I already trained several models myself using keras and tensorflow, however I haven't fine tuned another model and didn't use pytorch before yet, so I'm not sure if that is a right approach to do it.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to fine-tune the exact same model and came across some issues. Did you manage to figure it out?